# Is it possible to find reductions from problems in $\mathsf{NP}$ to SAT based solely on the certificate verification algorithm?

Tags: reductions, np, satisfiability, polynomial-time, polynomial-time-reductions

The following problem has made me ask this question:

> Given a boolean formula $\varphi(X)$ decide if there exists a quantification of $\varphi(X)$ with $k$ $\forall$ quantifiers that holds true. Assume that $k$ is bounded with $\mathcal O(\log n)$.

To clarify, the order of the quantifiers is arbitrary. I.e. the resulting formula is of the form $Q_{a_1}x_{b_1}\ Q_{a_2}x_{b_2}\cdots Q_{a_n}x_{b_n}:\varphi(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ where each $Q$ is either $\exists$ or $\forall$, and there is no connection between $a_i$ and $b_j$ for any $i,j$.

This problem is clearly in $\mathsf{NP}$: first the proof would show the QBF with $k$ $\forall$-quantified variables, then it would expand it into an unquantified formula with at most polynomial ($2^k$) blowup and show that this new formula is satisfiable.

However, in the worst case there are $\omega(poly(n)\cdot n^{\log n})$ candidate quantifications of $\varphi(X)$ and therefore it seems non-trivial to find a poly-time reduction.

But maybe there is an easier method? Is it possible to find a poly-time reduction to SAT based solely on the proof verification algorithm?

Comment: @D.W. The reduction from SAT is easy: just set $k$ at $0$. What I mean is that every certificate from this problem must somehow translate to a certificate for some instance of SAT problem, and there must be a deterministic poly-time construction for it. So I'm trying to think how such a translation is possible. But I guess what Steven has suggested technically would work.

Comment: @D.W. Sure! I have turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding a reduction to SAT is easy but tedious.
Write down a description of polynomial-time Turing machine $T$ that checks the certificate (as you have argued in your question, such a Turing machine exists), then encode $T$ into a SAT formula $\psi$ that has a variable for each input symbol of the certificate (plus additional variables as needed) such that $\psi$ admits a satisfying assignment iff there is a way to chose the symbols of the certificate and a corresponding valid computation path that causes $T$ to accept.

This can be done following the construction used by the [proof of the Cook–Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem).